# Google Calendar or any other calendar code

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

Hello I want to know if I can use the Google Calendar or any code of a calendar for my page. I create a simple page with login and register box, but now I want at the 3rd page to have a calendar.

For example:

1.The user John can have his calendar and he can create events and other..

2.The Emily is another user and she have another calendar with another events that she want to add..

I know I need to do this using database, but I don't find something useful..:(

Answer (score 1):

You can find [this project](https://github.com/sabapk/Node-CalendarApp) useful. If you are not comfortable using MVC framework, you can get an idea from project and build in pure javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a google calendar on your page.

How to embedd and customize:
[GoogleCalendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)

Comment: Why the downvote? He ask if it is possible to use google calendar. I showed him a solution. Both of his example fit so it is a perfekt answer to his question.